# Access Session Variable From jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, arrays

1) If I have a users login details stored as sessions then how do I access this data via jQuery?

2) Are Sessions the best way to globally store user details so that they can be accessed via any front-end page?

Comment: It is already in JSON format, why do you want to convert it into an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a cookie with the username in it if you want jQuery to know what it is.

Alternatively, you could set up an ajax request to a php page that returns the username for the active session id.

You can also just output PHP before Javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var username = "<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>";
</script>
```